Kungfu movie about 4 brothers
I am looking for the name of a kungfu movie. There is four men being taught by four humorous teachers. One jumps from a sewer pit and learns that tapping foot on surfaces of water makes him jump higher. One toughens skin by twisting himself in bamboo, one breaks stone with his bare hands and one makes his palms like iron by pushing a grinding wheel till he crumbles the cement. The climax is they storm this fortress and fight with what they were taught. One jumps the walls, one breaks a wall down,one has arrows bounce off him the other can hit so hard he leaves his palm print in a pillar? 

Hi! Do you remember the approximate year or decade of release? Where\when did you see it?

The Four Assassins
IMDb:

"Four friends learn kung fu to avenge the death of their friend
  against the manchus."

You can watch the complete movie here:



Here is a clip, at 1:16 you can see the guy pushing the grinding wheel:



Two pictures of the guy pushing the grinding wheel:


